# rollapplyr issue with valid xts object: 'match' requires vector arguments

Tags: r, match, xts

I'm attempting to use `rollapplyr` to do sliding window analysis of a 500 row single column xts object called `xtstmp` using `stl`, head of `xtstmp` as follows:

```
                      Close
2012-08-15 09:30:00 3434.51
2012-08-15 10:00:00 3426.24
2012-08-15 10:30:00 3438.41
2012-08-15 11:00:00 3436.79
2012-08-15 11:30:00 3441.57
```

Output of `dput(head(xtstmp,10))` is:

```
structure(c(4310.77, 4332.24, 4334.37, 4334.37, 4363.17, 4372.78, 
4372.61, 4360.63, 4371.45, 4377.86), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = structure("timeDate", package = "timeDate"), tclass = structure("timeDate", package = "timeDate"), .indexTZ = "GMT", tzone = "GMT", .CLASS = "double", index = structure(c(1369400400, 
1369404000, 1369407600, 1369411200, 1369414800, 1369648800, 1369652400, 
1369656000, 1369659600, 1369663200), tzone = "GMT", tclass = structure("timeDate", package = "timeDate")), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L))
```

But whenever I try to use this with `rollapplyr` like this:

```
rollapplyr(xtstmp,100,function(x) stl(x, s.window="periodic"),fill=NA)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments
```

Using Rerun with debug in Rstudio halts in the match function:

```
function (x, table, nomatch = NA_integer_, incomparables = NULL) 
.Internal(match(x, table, nomatch, incomparables))
```

...where the arguments `x` and `table` have formal class timeDate (POSIXct), which presumably the match function does not regard as the vector input it requires?

Is this a known issue or just an obvious error on my part? (Simply applying `stl` to the whole of `xtstmp` works fine)

Comment: Please edit the output of `dput(head(xtstmp,10))` into your question.